# Is there a way to get a React component's internal values when I click a button on the parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, react-component

Suppose I have a component like this -

```
const MyForm = ({ formId }) => (
   <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Full name"></input>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email"></input>
   </div>
)

export default MyForm;
```

And then I have my `App.js` like so -

```
import React from "react";
import MyForm from "./MyForm";

const App = () => (
   <div id="app">
      <MyForm formId="formOne"></MyForm>
      <MyForm formId="formTwo"></MyForm>
      <button onClick={
         () => {
            // Here, when the user clicks the button,
            // I want to get values of both the textboxes,
            // from both the component instances
         }
      }>Submit</button>
   </div>
)

export default App;
```

So basically, what I want is - when the `button` is clicked, I want to be able to retrieve the values of the textboxes. One way to do this is to raise an event from inside `MyForm.js` so that every text change is bubbled up to the parent via a callback function prop, but that feels too cumbersome, especially if the form has a lot of fields. Is there any simple or direct way to do this? Do I need to involve global state management tools like Redux?

Comment: You can utilize the react context and use hooks inside `MyForm`  to update the value and the data will be accessible to your `App`

Answer (score 0):

State inside a component is specific only to that component, the parent , children or sibling of a component have no idea of the state. The only way to communicate the value from one component to another component is via props . In your case, what we need is a state to reside at the `App` which can then be passed as a prop to both the `MyForm` Components.

**App.js**

```
const [ formState, setFormState ] = useState({ formOne: {fullName: '', Email: ''}, formTwo: '' })

const updateFormValues = (formId, key, value) => { 
   const stateCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(formState));
   const formToUpdate = stateCopy[formId];
   formToUpdate[key] = value;
   setFormState(stateCopy)
}

<MyForm formId="formOne" values={formState.formOne} updateFormValues={updateFormValues}></MyForm>
<MyForm formId="formTwo" values={formState.formTwo} updateFormValues={updateFormValues}></MyForm>
```

**MyForm.js**

```
const MyForm = ({ formId, values, updateFormValues }) => {
     const onInputChange = (e, key) => {
        updateFormValues(formId, key, e.target.value)
     }

return(
       <div>
          <input type="text" onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e, 'fullName'} value={values.fullName} placeholder="Full name"></input>
          <input type="text" onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e, 'email'} value={values.email} placeholder="Email"></input>
       </div>
    )}
    
    export default MyForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

To have access to data inside children components you need to lift the state to the parent component.

[One-way data flow](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

> Identify every component that renders something based on that state.
> Find a common owner component (a single component above all the components that need the state in the hierarchy).
> Either the common owner or another component higher up in the hierarchy should own the state.
> If you can’t find a component where it makes sense to own the state, create a new component solely for holding the state and add it somewhere in the hierarchy above the common owner component.

One way to do this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function MyForm(props) {
const { handleChange, values } = props;
return (
    <div>
        <label htmlFor="name">Your name</label>
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Full name"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.name}
            id="name"
            name="name"
        />
        <label htmlFor="email">Your email</label>
        <input
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.email}
            id="email"
            name="email"
        />
    </div>
        );
   } 



function App() {
const [values, setValues] = useState({ name: "", email: "" });

const handleChange = (event) => {
    const updatedForm = { ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value };
    setValues(updatedForm);
};

return (
    <div id="app">
        <MyForm
            formId="formOne"
            values={values}
            handleChange={handleChange}
        ></MyForm>

        <button
            onClick={() => {
                console.log(values);
            }}
        >
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>
);
}

export default App;
```